# Crystal Reports for VS2010 Toolbar Icons not working.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, crystal-reports-2010

I am trying to get a simple VS2010 MVC2 app using Crystal Reports version 13 to work. My app uses a SQL Server stored proc to pull data and populate a CR report. This works great and I can see the results in the CR Viewer no problem. The issue is the toolbar icons. No matter what I click they fail to work. For instance the next page icon brings up the wait popup and never goes away. Print button does nothing except in Chrome where it brings up a dialog but that does nothing when Export is clicked. Right now the app I am trying to get to work is a bare bones prototype new VS2010 MVC2 project. It has one report , uses the CR viewer and that's it. If anyone can see what is causing this toolbar issue I will be much appreciative. If you have a small sample app with a multi-page report of this setup - even better! Thanks for you help in advance. I am desperate to get this working. Here is the relative parts of my code.

BTW - if you do try this in VS2010 - remove the table css from the Site.css file - it causes the toolbar to not show.

My aspx:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.ToolbarStyle toolbarStyle = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ToolbarStyle();
        toolbarStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ToolbarStyle = toolbarStyle;
        CrystalReportViewer1.HasCrystalLogo = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = ToolPanelViewType.None;


        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlcon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ULS_db1;User ID=uls2008;Password=uls2008");
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        comand.Connection = sqlcon;
        comand.CommandText = "GetInvTest";
        comand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        string strReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/test.rpt");

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter sqladp = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(comand);

        sqlcon.Open();
        sqladp.Fill(ds, "myDataSet");

        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument oRpt = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

        oRpt.Load(strReportPath);

        oRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt;

        sqlcon.Close();

    }

</script>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div>
```

My web.config:

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  </assemblies>

<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an MVC issue. Same problem was seen here:

[ASP.NET MVC VS2010 Crystal Reports Beta 2 Can't Print, Export, Zoom, or Change Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902195/asp-net-mvc-vs2010-crystal-reports-beta-2-cant-print-export-zoom-or-change-p)

I wound up using an iframe in my view with the webform which had the CRV in it as the source. Worked like a charm.